# How get data stored in Microsoft band 1?

Tags: android, sdk, bluetooth, microsoft-band

I'm trying  to work with one microsoft band and I want to access to some data values catched with this device. I understand that this band has some kind of internal storage where save the data during a period of time and later it is synchronized through Bluetooth and the Microsoft Health app, am I wrong? If I am right, how long this information is maintained?

I want to know if I can get this stored data in the band directly in my own app with the Microsoft Band SDK. I have seen the examples, and I can get the real time data in the device, but I'm really interested in all data stored during a period of time (heart rate in workout sessions, pedometer, calories) is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen the SDK documentation for Android, and I still have some questions about the data access.

For example, I have read that the band provides the total number of calories the wearer has burned since the band was last factory-reset, but if I am some days without synchronize the band, I am going to receive the total number of calories burned in these days, but then, how can I know the calories number that I have burned one concrete day? and I know that the Microsoft Health app gets this information. I want to know if I can get too this information or this is only for Microsoft app.

In the same way, I know that I can get the current heart rate in beats per minute, but I would like to get the complete data with heart rate of an activity session that I have done without the mobile connected to the band, is it possible?

I have seen too that the Microdoft Health app shows details and a summary about actual sleep, but I haven't seen anything about this point in the SDK documentation, is this information restricted for Microsoft Health app? (image: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/j0kyrrj9n9cvtab/AADaAWEMqvXrvgovrFMH-jSqa?dl=0)

I hope I have explained correctly my doubts.

Comment: You can get hourly/summary data using the (preview) Microsoft Health Cloud REST API, but there is an assumption that the Band is regularly sync'ing with the Cloud (via the Health application).  If you want to calculate calories burned or steps taken over some period of time (e.g. hour/day) then you must have an application that periodically connects to the Band and retrieves the current calorie/step values. Using the current and previous values you can calculate your own summaries.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways for an application to retrieve biometric data generated by a Band:

1. The application connects to the Band using the SDK and subscribes to real-time events for specific sensors.
2. The application uses the [(preview) Microsoft Health Cloud REST API](http://developer.microsoftband.com/cloudAPI) to retrieve hourly/daily summary data or data related to specific activities (e.g. sleep, bike, run, workout, etc.).  Note that application can retrieve only data that has been sync'd with the Cloud via the Microsoft Health application prior to the request. Applications do not have access to accumulated data on the Band that has not yet been sync'd with the Cloud.